# Can Python win32com use Visio (or any program) without popping up a GUI?

Tags: python, com, visio, win32com

I have a Python script using win32com to open a Visio file and dump each tab as `.png` files.  It briefly flashes the Visio gui up on the screen when it does this.  Is there any way to do this in the background without loading the Visio window?

```
import win32com.client
visio = win32com.client.Dispatch("Visio.Application")
visio.Documents.Open(filepath)
...
visio.Quit()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
visio = win32com.client.Dispatch("Visio.InvisibleApp")
```

should create a Visio instance that is invisible.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa201815(v=office.10).aspx

Answer (score 2):

You can control the visibility of the application by using the `Visible` property.

Example: to hide the Visio application window

```
visio.Visible = 0
```

Example: to show the Visio application window

```
visio.Visible = 1
```

When you create the initial instance it will still be visible. Only afterwards can you make the window hidden. I don't know a way of forcing the application to *start* invisibly.

Comment: I had this in the code originally, but as you say the window still flashes open.